# Define multiprocessing loops from config file

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to read a set of sensors in parallel with concurrent loops, but each system has a different set of sensors.

I currently have:

```
with open(inputfilelocation, 'r') as f:
    sensorlist = json.load(f)

while True:
    for sensor in sensorlist:
        H, T = read_sensor(sensor['model'], sensor['address'])
            send_data(H, T)
    time.sleep(60)
```

which reads them all, then sleeps for a minute. But now I want to specify how frequently to sample each sensor.

I could do:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def loop_a():
  while True:
    #Sample and send data
    time.sleep(sensor_a_delay)

def loop_b():
  while True:
    #Sample and send data
    time.sleep(sensor_b_delay)

Process(target=loop_a).start()
Process(target=loop_b).start()
```

but then I would need to know at the very least how many sensors I have.

Is there any way to define these loops on the fly?

Edit: I've tried this:

```
def loop_a(sleeptime, string):
  while 1:
    print(string)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)

Process(target=loop_a(5,"foo")).start()
Process(target=loop_a(2,"bar")).start()
```

but only the "foo" loop runs.

Comment: Use a loop to create the processes and a function with arguments. And BTW threading should do the task in a lighter way.

Comment: OK, I fiddled around a bit and figured out the answer (below). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured out what Klaus meant. This solves my problem:

```
import time
import json
import threading

with open('sensorlist.json', 'r') as f:
    sensorlist = json.load(f)

def sensorloop(model,address,delay):
    while True:
        H, T = read_sensor(model, address)
        send_data(H, T)
        time.sleep(delay)

for sensor in sensorlist:
    x = threading.Thread(target=sensorloop,
                         args = (sensor['model'],
                                 sensor['address'],
                                 sensor['delay'])
                         )
    x.start()
```